# Scalamock "annotation" library

Tags: unit-testing, scala, mocking, sbt

I try to use mocks in my application with Scalamock, but what I want to mock is a class, with parameters. I saw scalamock doc, and they say to mock classes, I must import `org.scalamock.annotation.mock` to use some functions. [My reference is scalatest docs](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/testing_with_mock_objects#generatedMocks).

"annotation" seems to be nonexistent...

My sbt dependencies :

```
"org.scalamock" % "scalamock-scalatest-support_2.10" % "3.0.1" % "test"
"org.scalamock" % "scalamock-core_2.10" % "3.0.1"
```

I think I forgot one library, but I don't know what it is..

EDIT :

Test code :

```
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory

class AuthenticationServiceTest extends FlatSpec with MockFactory
{
    "A user" should " be authenticated" in
    {
      val user = mock[User]
      val tenant = mock[Tenant]
      inSequence {
        (authenticate(tenant, user) _).expects.returning(true)
      }

      assert(authenticate(tenant, user))
    }
}
```

Classes :

```
class User (
  val username    : String,
  var password    : String,
  var firstname   : String,
  var lastname    : String,
  var isActivated : Boolean,
  val tenantId    : TenantId
             )
{}

class Tenant (
  val tenantId    : TenantId,
  val companyName : String,
  var fullAddress : String,
  var email       : String,
  var phone       : String,
  var isActivated : Boolean
               )
{}
```

Method to test :

```
def authenticate(tenant: Tenant, user: User): Boolean = { 
//code... 
}
```

Error :

```
[error] Unspecified value parameters username, password, firstname, ...
[error]       val user = mock[User]
[error]                      ^
[error] one error found
[error] (test:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 9 s, completed 17 oct. 2013 09:16:18
```

Comment: Consider using double % instead of using `_2.10` suffix. 

`"org.scalamock" %% "scalamock-scalatest-support" % "3.0.1" % "test"`

Answer (score 2):

You probably read the section *generated mocks* which relies on **ScalaMock Compiler plugin** and you don't have dependency to it.

In my opinion it is OK, because you don't need this compiler plugin to use scala mock. To use scala mock with **scala test** you can use `mock` function provided by `org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory`. See below simple test with imports:

```
import org.scalatest.FreeSpec
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory

class MySpec extends FreeSpec with MockFactory {

  class C {
    def method: String = "ABC"
  }

  abstract class AC {
    def method: String
  }

  trait T {
    def method: String
  }

  trait M[A] {
    def method: A
  }

  "You don't need to create real objects, you can mock" - {
    "class" in {
      val m = mock[C]
      inSequence {
        (m.method _).expects.returning("X")
      }
      assert(m.method === "X")
    }
    "abstract class" in {
      val m = mock[AC]
      inSequence {
        (m.method _).expects.returning("X")
      }
      assert(m.method === "X")
    }
    "trait" in {
      val m = mock[T]
      inSequence {
        (m.method _).expects.returning("X")
      }
      assert(m.method === "X")
    }
    "trait parametrized by type" in {
      val m = mock[M[String]]
      inSequence {
        (m.method _).expects.returning("X")
      }
      assert(m.method === "X")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! But IDE and SBT can't resolve `.expects` method... And my mock doesn't work (I'll edit my post)

Comment: My IDE (Intellij) as well doesn't know what is `.expects`. This is because scalamock under the hood uses **macros**. In SBT  it compiles without problems. To be more clear, my SBT config is:
`sbt.version=0.12.2`

```scalacOptions ++= List("-feature", "-language:implicitConversions"),
 scalaVersion := "2.10.2",
 resolvers ++=  List(
    "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10.0" % "2.0.M5" % "test",
    ("org.scalamock" %% "scalamock-scalatest-support" % "3.0.1" exclude("org.scalatest", "scalatest_2.10")) % "test"
  )```

Comment: I have nearly the same code and SBT can't compile, with a message error that I add in my topic..